How to create a 60 seconds timer in a pallet
we are creating a game which give the player a 60 seconds rounds to play. How can we set a timer of 60 seconds in a substrate pallet?

Always consider using the block number first at runtime.
trait Config {
  RoundTime: Get<BlockNumberFor<T>>,
}

If your chain's block time is 12 seconds, then approximately 1 minute passes for every 5 blocks.
impl Config for Runtime {
  RoundTime = ConstU32<5>,
}

